# Show outside element on table row mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a `table` by using `display:table` property of CSS. Everything is working well.

But today my company has different requirement, that is:
Some buttons will show with `table row` `mouse over` and its design won’t be inside any table cell.

I have written the code following below.

```
<div class="table-responsive ni-deleteable">
    <div class="ni-table" ni-table-rowno="1">
        <div class="ni-table-header">
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-deleteable ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">GMTtype</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-deleteable ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">FabOpt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-deleteable ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">Sector</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-deleteable ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">Wstg%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ni-table-row">
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ni-table-cell ni-clickable ui-droppable">
                <div contenteditable="true">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="placeholder-handle btn-group">
                <button class="handle-add btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" value=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                <button class="handle-remove btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" value=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ni-table {
    display: table;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

    .ni-table > .ni-table-header, .ni-table > .ni-table-row, .ni-table > .ni-table-footer {
        display: table-row;
        min-height: 22px;
    }

        .ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell, .ni-table > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell, .ni-table > .ni-table-footer > .ni-table-cell {
            display: table-cell;
            /*border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;*/
            border-bottom: none;
            border-right: none;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 22px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            /*text-align: center;*/
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell, .ni-table > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell, .ni-table > .ni-table-footer > .ni-table-cell:first-child {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
            }
        /*.ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell, .ni-table > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell, .ni-table > .ni-table-footer > .ni-table-cell:last-child {
                border-bottom: none;
            }*/
        .ni-table > .ni-table-header .ni-table-cell:last-child, .ni-table > .ni-table-row .ni-table-cell:last-child, .ni-table > .ni-table-footer .ni-table-cell:last-child {
            border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        }

    .ni-table > .ni-table-header {
        background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
        /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 0%, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) 50%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 100%);
        /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)));
        /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 0%, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) 50%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 100%);
        /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 0%, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) 50%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 100%);
        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 0%, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) 50%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 100%);
        /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 0%, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) 50%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 100%);
        /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e0e0e0', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=0);
        /* IE6-9 */
        text-align: left;
    }

        .ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell {
            color: #000;
            min-height: 22px;
            font-size: 12px;
            /*margin: 0px 3px;*/
            border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: relative;
        }
        .ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell div{
            margin: 0px 3px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

            .ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell span {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                white-space: nowrap;
                height: 22px;
                line-height: 22px;
            }
    .ni-table > .ni-table-cell label {
        margin: 0 3px;
    }
    .ni-table > .ni-table-cell input[type=text] {
        margin: 0 -3px;
    }
    .ni-table > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell {
        color: #000;
        min-height: 22px;
        font-size: 12px;
        /*padding: 0px 3px;*/
        border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: left;
        /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* display: block; */
    }

        .ni-table > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell > div {
            overflow: hidden;
        }



    /*.ni-table > .ni-table-row:nth-child(odd) > .ni-table-cell {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.ni-table > .ni-table-row:nth-child(odd) > .ni-table-cell {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}*/

    .ni-table > .ni-table-row:hover > .ni-table-cell {
        background-color: #d7d7d7;
    }

    .ni-table > .ni-table-footer {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

[image]

The `div` with class name `placeholder-handle` is containing those `buttons` which will show `mouseover` on `ni-table-row`.

> **The problem is:** The `placeholder-handle` is occupying the space. But
>   my need is: it will show only on `mouseover`. Any idea will help me a lot.

Comment: Tell me if my answer is what you need or I write another code.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude. it is taking space. it will show the only mouseover but it won't take any space.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this:

```
 .ni-table-row .placeholder-handle button {
       display: none;  // hide when no state
 }
 .ni-table-row:hover .placeholder-handle button {
       display: inline-block;  // show when hover
 }
```

### EDIT

So the best I see with your code is insert the buttons in the last table-cell and make the trick with absolute positioning:

```
<div class="ni-table-cell ni-clickable ui-droppable">
    <div contenteditable="true">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="placeholder-handle btn-group">
        <button class="handle-add btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" value=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
        <button class="handle-remove btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" value=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 .ni-table-row {
       position:relative;
  }
 .ni-table-row .placeholder-handle {
       display: none;  /* hide when no state */
       position: absolute;
       width: 100px; /* adjust here that you need */
       right: -100px; /* adjust (width * -1) */
 }
 .ni-table-row:hover .placeholder-handle {
       display:  block;  /* show when hover */
 }
```

Comment: placeholder-handle is taking space. no need space.

Comment: Table column is created dynamically. so if I add this control into last column cell, it can be deleted according to my business scenario.

Comment: Finally I help you? You can upvote my answer. Thank you!